# PHP self processing form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to set up errors to pop up if they do not fill in the form section. The Name and email portion portion work when I hit submit but the comment section does not. I noticed when I start to type into the comment section it starts over about 5 spaces in so it looks like there is something in the field. Once I delete that and submit the form the error message appears in the comment section not to the right of the field like the 2 fields above? Help please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Guestbook</title>
<style type="text/css">
.errors { color: ff0000; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

```
<?php    /* Opening tag of php */

  //initialize error array
  $errors=array();

  //main logic
  if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    checkForm();
}
  else{
    printForm();
}
  //begin functions
  function checkForm()
{
  global $errors;
  if($_POST[name] == "")
      $errors['name']="<span class=\"errors\"><b>&nbsp Please, enter your Name!</span>";
  if($_POST[email] == "")
      $errors['email']="<span class=\"errors\"><b>&nbsp Please, enter your Email!</span>";
  if($_POST[myComments] == "")
      $errors['myComments']="<span class=\"errors\"><b>&nbsp Please, enter something!             </span>";          

  if(count($errors) !=0)
    printForm();
  else
    confirm();
} //end checkForm function

function confirm(){
print "<h2>Thank you for signing my guestbook</h2>";    
print "<p>Name: ".$_POST['name'];
print "</p><p>Email: ".$_POST['email'];    
print "</p><p>Comment: ".$_POST['myComments'];
print "</p><br />"; //Extra line break.

print "<em>Today is "  . date('F jS, Y.')."</em><br />"; //Extra line break. 
} //end confirm

function printForm() 
{
global $errors;
$place = $_POST[place];
// My old code I am trying to combine
print <<< HERE
 <h1>Please sign my guestbook.</h1>
 <form method="POST" action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}"> 
 <table> 
 <tr>
 <td class=name </td>Name: <br />
 <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{$_POST['name']}">
 {$errors['name']}</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td class=email</td>Email: <br />
 <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value"{$_POST['email']}">
 {$errors['email']}</td>
 </tr>  

 <tr>
 <td class=myComments</td>Comments:<br />
 <td><textarea type="text" name="myComments" id="mycomments" rows="4" cols="40" value"                 {$_POST['myComments']}">
 {$errors['myComments']}</textarea></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><input type=submit name="submit" value="send"><input type="reset" name="clear" value=Clear>  </td>
 </tr>

 </table>
 </form>

 <br>
HERE;
 print "Today is "  . date('F jS, Y.')."<br>"; //Date printed in page below form.
 print "Form designed by Kevin O'Leary "."<br>"; //Date printed in page below form.
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your missing =" " in your textareas around value, which is not an attribute of <textarea> and should be omitted... and your also missing the " " around the type attribute here...`<input type=submit name="submit"`... should be ...`<input type="submit" name="submit"...` You should really consider learning HTML syntax before you submit questions related to it on this site.

Answer (score 0):

TextArea doesn't have a `value` or `type` attribute (and even if it did, you don't have an equal sign after value).  Any spaces (line breaks, space, tabs, etc) between the TextArea and /TextArea will show up, so don't do a line break between the opening and closing tags.

You probably want your TextArea markup to look something like this:

```
<textarea name="myComments" id="mycomments" rows="4" cols="40">{$_POST['myComments']}</textarea> {$errors['myComments']}
```

This will cause the `$_POST['myComments']` to show up in the TextArea, and `$errors['myComments']` to show to the right of the textarea (or below, if the textarea is too wide and it causes it to wrap).

Also, your email field doesn't have an equal sign after value, either.

Take a look at this for more information on textarea usage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML_Elements/textarea